# Accessing JSP form data with in the Struts 2 Action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I don't understand how to access form data within the JSP page inside my `Action` class

**`login.jsp`:**

```html
 <div class="well">
    <form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="hr/login/" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="UserEmail"><i class="fa fa-user" title="Enter Your username"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="" required title="Please enter you username" placeholder="Enter Username" />
            </div>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="UserPasswordMatch"><i class="fa fa-lock" title="Choose password"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordmatch" name="passwordmatch" value="" required title="Enter your password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**`BookingAction.java`:**

```java
public class BookingAction {
    private String name;
    
    HotelReservationServceImpl service = new HotelReservationServceImpl();

       public String execute() throws Exception {
        
          return "success";
       }
       
       public String loginExecute() 
       {
           
           
           return "success";
       }
       public String getName() {
          return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
       }
}
```

I also have a `User` class with private attributes which include `username` and `password` with getters and setters.

**`service.java`:**

```java
public class HotelReservationServceImpl implements IHotelReservationService {

    
    HotelReservationDAOImpl dbcon = new HotelReservationDAOImpl();
    @Override
    public int login(String username, String passwrd) {
        if(username.isEmpty() || passwrd.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.print(" Enter username and password ");
            
        }
        else
        {
        int i = dbcon.login(username, passwrd);
        
        }
        
        
        //dbcon.dbConnector();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
     
      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.reservation.action.BookingAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
      <action name="login"
       class="com.reservation.action.BookingAction" 
            method="loginExecute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Use struts tags for form and their input fields where its possible. Bind form controls to the action bean which is your model. See developer console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use Struts tags to bind the form to the action and input fields to action properties.

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<s:form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="login" novalidate="novalidate">    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="UserEmail"><i class="fa fa-user" title="Enter Your username"></i></span>
            <s:textfield cssClass="form-control" id="username" name="user.username" value="" required title="Please enter you username" placeholder="Enter Username" />
        </div>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="UserPasswordMatch"><i class="fa fa-lock" title="Choose password"></i></span>
            <s:password cssClass="form-control" id="passwordmatch" name="user.password" value="" required title="Enter your password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
</s:form>
```

To bind the form you should set the action name to the form tag. To bind input fields you should set property names to the struts input tags.

The properties are in the `User` bean that you should aggregate to the action class.

```java
private User user;
public User getUser() { return user; }
public void setUser(User user) { this.user = user; }
```

If you don't want to generate extra HTML to the page use

```xml
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"/>
```